# Selenium Slider

Tags: python, selenium

I have a slider that I want to select randomly using Selenium, like send_keys.

My current process:

```
move=ActionChains(driver)

move.click_and_hold(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="age-selector"]/div/div/div[1]/div[6]')).move_by_offset(random.randint(-18,100),0).release().perform()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="age-selector"]/div/div/div[1]/div[6]').click()

move.click_and_hold(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="age-selector"]/div/div/div[1]/div[7]')).move_by_offset(random.randint(-18,100),0).release().perform()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="age-selector"]/div/div/div[1]/div[7]').click()
```

I don't think that this is efficient. Sometimes error appears aswell.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, Can you share the website?

Comment: You must create a account on https://lp.unserkleinesgeheimnis.de/lp16/?c=752&ut and then here it is: https://www.unserkleinesgeheimnis.de/settings/profile

Comment: It's a bot for a customer lol. How do I add NSFW?

Comment: Oh I have to create account? can you try yourself by changing the attribute `aria-valuenow` manually in HTML? what happens? does slider moves?

Comment: No, it doesn't move when I change it in HTML. But when I pull the slider manually the value changes.

Comment: don't think that this is efficient. Sometimes error appears aswell. - What is the error ?

Comment: @cruisepandey not really an error. Like the slider changes for example from 1 to 10 but suddenly after one second again from 10 to 34